# Restangular POST always empty

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, restangular

I think I'm not understanding how a POST is done in a RESTful api. When creating a new object in Restangular with this:

```
var user = {name: "John", id:"123"};
Restangular.one('building','5').post(user);
```

I expect it to pass a $_POST array with the values of user to the url example.com/api/building/5

And right know it's doing a POST request to the correct script but the $_POST array is empty. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm the creator of Restangular. Posts should be done to collections, not to elements. So, if you want to add a user to the building, you should do something like:

```
Restangular.one("building", 5).post('users', user).then(function(postedUser) {
    console.log("Success");
})
```

Check the post method here: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods

The signature is path to subelement collection, element to POST.

Bests!

Comment: Good job on Restangular ;)

Comment: @mgonto What means the string 'users' in your answer? Thank you.

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk 'users' is the key for users collection object.
Something like this 
{
'users' : [{
"id" : 1
},
{
"id" : 2
}]
}

Comment: 'users' is the last part of your REST API URL. It should be `example.com/api/building/5/users` according to REST API rules. And you were trying to send to it to entity (building with id = 5).

Comment: So... to be clear, this is wrong. The semantics of POST are up to the server to dictate and may be entirely appropriate. Sure, it would be nice if PATCH were used instead (assuming the content makes sense of a patch) but that's not relevant.