# Angular JS and Restangular: How to include a header and parameters in POST request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, restangular

I am trying to make a POST request that has a header and parameters. This is currently what my code looks like:

```
var login = Restangular.one('authentication/location',{Authorization:
    'token'}).post({grant_type:'password', username:'n@n.com',password:
    'password',scope:'my_scope'});
```

How do I correctly add my header and parameters using this style?

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the element `post()` method is:

```
post(subElement, elementToPost, [queryParams, headers])
```

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods

Headers in Restangular are set like this:

```
{'header name': 'header value'}
```

The `subElement` should be a collection, see this question for reference: [Restangular POST always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302395/restangular-post-always-empty)